# mysql: difference between values in one column

Tags: mysql, window-functions

this board helped me a few times in the past.

My challange: I want to get the difference between the values within one column.

The table looks like this:

```
id  |  channel_id  |  timestamp   |  value
4515|    7         |1519771680000 |  7777
4518|    8         |1519772160000 |  6666
4520|    7         |1519772340000 |  8888
```

- id: Internal ID from Datasource. In some cases it's ordered, in other cases not. We cannot thrust this order.
- channel_id: Different data sources.
- timestamp: unix timestamp.
- value: measured value.

What I want to do:

Filter (e.g. channel_id = 7).
Calculate the difference between one timestamp and the next one. In this example: 8888-7777

I found an solution on another database but I cannot transfer it to mysql as the windows functions are very limited. Has somebody of you an idea how to get a solution which can be used in select statements?

Thx and KR
Holger

Comment: You can filter and rank the rows for specific channel based on time stamp. Then join that with itself saying table1.rank = table2.rank + 1. Then you can get the difference. You might need to look up how to rank on mysql since the function doesn't work here like it does in mysql.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `Calculate the difference between one timestamp and the next one.`? You want the difference between the column `value` from one record with a matching channel id and another with a different timestamp, right?

Comment: @clinomaniac: Hi, the ranking and selfjoin is something which i am working on / trying to get to work but struggeling. (select ....  (AT)rowid:=(AT)rowid+1 as rowid .. . FROM ... (SELECT (AT)rowid:=0) as init, .... but i cannot use it in the join.

Comment: @Sloan Thrasher: "calculate the difference": same channel id, timestamp and the direct previous timestamp (next lower one), difference between values. Thats what i try to do.

Comment: @holgerabend does the solution provided by Used_By_Already not help? That seems like it should work for your case.

Comment: @clinomaniac thanks for your hint. I thought initially he changes data structure by his Schema Setup. I tried to execute his proposal but unfortunately the workbench aborts after 300 sec. the connection. Error Code 2013. In the table are 119402 entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for all your support. I tried a lot and created "my" solution based on a stored procedure. It is not as performant as it could be but it delivers the required values.

The code is running in a loop with a max size of repetitions in the script execution to avoid an endless step :)

```
#Auswahl größer CH10-Wert
set @var_max_ch10vz =
    (
    select max(data.timestamp)
    from volkszaehler.data 
    where data.channel_id=10
    )
;
#Auswahl kleinster offener Wert aus SBFSPOT
set @var_min_sbfspot = 
    (
    select min(data.timestamp_unix*1000)
    from sbfspot_u.data
    where 
        data.timestamp_vzjoin is null 
        and data.timestamp_unix >1522096327
        and data.timestamp_unix*1000 < @var_max_ch10vz
    )
;
#Abgleich gegen VZ von unten
set @var_max_vz =
    (
    select min(data.timestamp)
    from volkszaehler.data 
    where data.channel_id=10 and data.timestamp >= @var_min_sbfspot
    )
;
#Abgleich gegen VZ von oben
set @var_min_vz =
    (
    select max(data.timestamp)
    from volkszaehler.data 
    where data.channel_id=10 and data.timestamp <= @var_min_sbfspot
    )
;
#Auswahl join Zeitstempel
set @vz_join_timestamp =
    (
        select tmp.uxtimestamp 
        from (
            select @var_max_vz as uxtimestamp, abs(@var_min_sbfspot-@var_max_vz) as diff
            UNION
            select @var_min_vz as uxtimestamp, abs(@var_min_sbfspot-@var_min_vz) as diff
            ) tmp
        order by tmp.diff asc
        limit 1
    )
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the two rows to compare (ie subtract) by joining the table to itself:

```
SELECT
    a.channel_id,
    a.timestamp,
    b.timestamp,
    a.value - b.value as `difference`
FROM table a
JOIN table b
ON a.channel_id = b.channel_id and a.timestamp <> b.timestamp and a.value > b.value
GROUP BY a.channel_id
ORDER BY a.channel_id
```

Comment: I don't think the solution is quite that simple. What if the value goes down? What if there are multiple values greater than the current one?

Comment: @clinomaniac,you make some good points, but based on what the OP put in their question, this is at least a starting point.

Comment: Hi, the values won't go down. They stay as they are or they increase slightly. so it will happen that the timestamp changes and the value stays constant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "correlated subquery" for this as seen below [(also see this demo)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4fe1f/4). When MySQL implements window functions such a `LEAD()` you could use those instead.

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`id` int, `channel_id` int, `timestamp` bigint, `value` int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`id`, `channel_id`, `timestamp`, `value`)
VALUES
    (4515, 7, 1519771680000, 7777),
    (4518, 8, 1519772160000, 6666),
    (4520, 7, 1519772340000, 8888)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
      id
    , channel_id
    , timestamp
    , value
    , nxt_value
    , nxt_value - value as diff
from (
    select
          t1.id
        , t1.channel_id
        , t1.timestamp
        , t1.value
        , (select value from table1 as t2 
           where t2.channel_id = t1.channel_id
           and t2.timestamp > t1.timestamp
           order by t2.timestamp
           limit 1) nxt_value
    from table1 as t1
    ) as d
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4fe1f/4/0)**:

```
|   id | channel_id |     timestamp | value | nxt_value |   diff |
|------|------------|---------------|-------|-----------|--------|
| 4515 |          7 | 1519771680000 |  7777 |      8888 |   1111 |
| 4518 |          8 | 1519772160000 |  6666 |    (null) | (null) |
| 4520 |          7 | 1519772340000 |  8888 |    (null) | (null) |
```

Comment: This won't work as i cannot change the structure of the table.

Comment: The table structure has not changed. The result has a few columns but you can choose what you need from that.

Comment: @holgerabend **There is no change of table structure needed.** The proposed query includes new columns (nxt_value & diff) but they are simply calculated when you run the query.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from MySQL 8, you can use [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html), in case of which your query would look like this:

```
SELECT
  id, channel_id, timestamp, value,
  value - LAG(value, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY channel_id ORDER BY timestamp) difference
FROM my_table
```